# Exporting Gridview to excel asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net, export-to-excel

I tried exporting my Gridview data to excel but nothing happens when I clicked the button.
I have tried looking for the problem using breakpoint then it always stopped at
**gridData.RenderControl(htmlWrite);** then it will go out of the function

this is my code

```
            Response.Clear();

            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename = FileName.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
            System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
            System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
            gridData.RenderControl(htmlWrite);
            Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());

            Response.End();
```

UPDATE~

I tried using try catch to see what is the problem and i saw that when you have buttons inside the gridview it will not continue with the rendercontrol so the solution that came up is to disable all the controls and hide the buttons before rendercontrol and it proceeded to the next lines but when I got to **Response.End()** it returned an error of **thread was being aborted** so I look the web for another solution and i found the **HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();** and after that the error is gone but the excel output is still missing

Comment: Does this sample work? https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0c1bb2/export-gridview-to-excel/

Comment: @JeremyThompson that's where I got that code. When I tried looking for the problem using breakpoint it stops at rendercontrol and after that it will stop there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this kind of problem you have to put triggers outside of the **ContentTemplate**. maybe because **UpdatePanel** is not compatible with FileUpload.

*You need to include this to your code*

```
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="YourButtonID" />
    </Triggers>
```